# Как дождаться выполнения команды os.system

Tags: python

```
def clicked():
    DelDisk = (Locat[combo.current()])
    print('net use m: ' + DelDisk)
    os.system('net use m: /delete')
    os.system('net use m: ' + DelDisk)
```

Необходимо что бы при нажатии на кнопку удалялся подключенный сетевой диск и добавлялся новый. Когда нажимаю отдельную кнопку в которой отдельно     os.system('net use m: /delete') все отлично, если в эту функцию между удалением и подключением сетевого диска добавить задержку в 10 секунд тоже все работает, но если без задержки то диск не удаляется и не меняется на нужный. Могу ли я как то дождаться выполнения удаления прежде чем добавлять новый диск ?

Comment: Ну так поставьте задержку, например, 1 секунду: `time.sleep(0)`

Comment: Если бы мне подходил это некорректный вариант я бы не согдовал тему / задержки даже в 3 секунды не хватает и я не хочу брать с большим запасом это время тк пользователь в этот момент ждёт / мне нужно что бы после успешного выполнения команды сразу выполнялись следующие

Comment: Какая у вас ОС? Между ними могут быть различия

Comment: Попробуйте перейти на использование `subprocess.run`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: nomnoms12 уже дал ответ, но возможно, вам подойдет вариант объединения команд в цепочку ?  `os.system('net use m: /delete && net use m: ' + DelDisk')`